# How to find entities by type using CakePHP 2.2?

Tags: cakephp, model, filter, controller

Here's the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html) I've read and here's what I'm trying. First I set up my Model associations:

```
<?php
class Proveedor extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = 'Libro';
    public $displayField = 'Nombre';
}

<?php
class Libro extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = 'Proveedor';
}
```

Next, I created my controller and my action function:

```
public function filter($proveedorName = null) {

    // proveedorName is a string: wrox, apress, oreilly, etc.
    // I need to find all libros that have their 'Proveedor' as $proveedorName.

    $this->set('libros', $this->Libro->find('all', 
    array('conditions' => array('Libros.Proveedor.Name' => $proveedorName))));

    $this->set('proveedores', $this->Libro->Proveedor->find('list'));
}
```

This is the error message that's popping up:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Libros.Proveedor.Name' in 'where clause'
```

My use case is quite simple, from a dropdown list select the proveedor and have the website return a collection of books (`libros`) that come from that supplier (`proveedor`).

It's as if you visit: `www.google.com/cars/filter/nissan` - you want to see all Nissan cars.

Same principal here: `www.google.com/libros/filter/apress` - I want to fetch all books (`libros`) from proveedor (`supplier`) Apress.

For illustrative purposes, in C# using Entity Framework and Linq I can go:

```
var books = db.Libros.Where(x => x.Proveedor.Name == "Apress");
```

Can I do something similar with CakePHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
array('conditions' => array('Libros.Proveedor.Name' => $proveedorName))));
```

Should be:

```
array('conditions' => array('Proveedor.Name' => $proveedorName))));
```

And you database fields should be lower cased (name) and underscored, not upper cased (Name) or anything else. Follow the conventions, it will make things a lot more easy.

Comment: Still getting an error: `Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Proveedor.Name' in 'where clause'` it's as if CakePHP isn't following the foreign key associations of the database and looking for an actual column named `Proveedor.Name`.